# Recurrence partition basic

Tags: integer-partitions

I have some questions regarding (recurrence relation) for partitions, actually I do not know what is the exact term called (it was stated as partitions only in my guide book and upon doing some searches, it seems that the formula is somewhat different).

But I was taught this formula called Recurrence Relation for Partitions and my lecturer only gave 1 such example for such scenario:
[image: formula]

Anyway, while trying out some exercises such as finding P(10,2), I am able to write out/ break down using the formula as follows:

```
P(10,2) = P(8,1) + P(8,2) = 5
where P(8,2) gives (1+7), (2+6), (3+5), (4+4)
```

However, I run into some doubts when dealing with bigger numbers such as finding P(18,2). As I was taught writing out the possible steps as shown above, is 9 the maximum number allowed? And are there any simpler ways in getting around with such problems other than writing down all the steps?

Comment: Im not sure how are these defined. What is the value for $p(1,1)$? Can the values of $r$ and $n$ be negative? E.g. $p(3,2)=p(2,2)+p(2,1)=p(0,1)+p(0,2)+p(1,1)$ , it seems like you need to define for all value of $p(0,k)$

Comment: @user319071 I think it is about finding the number of sums $r_1+\dots+r_n=r$ where the $r_i$ are positive integers and there is an ordering $r_1\leq\cdots\leq r_n$. In that context $r<n\implies P(r,n)=0$ and $P(r,r)=1$.

Comment: Hi all, I added in a picture of how the formula looks like in my guide book, hopefully that helps

Comment: @user319071, I am not sure if this will helps, but `P(r,1) = 1`, `P(r,r) = 1`, `P(r,n) = 0 if n > r`, again, these are mentioned in my guide book

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case: $p(18,2)=p(16,1)+p(16,2)=1+p(14,1)+p(14,2)$

You see it all reduce to $\frac{18-2}{2}+p(2,2)=9$

**r=2 Case**

For any even number, $p(2r,2)=r$ because it can be expressed as:

$$p(2,2)+\sum_{i=1}^{r-1}p(2i,1) =1+(r-1)$$

For an odd number: 
$p(2r+1,2)=[p(2r-1,1)+p(2r-3,1)+...+p(3,1)+p(1,1)]+p(1,2)=r$

Which means for the case $n=2$,
$p(r,2)=\lfloor\frac{r}{2}\rfloor$

**r=3 Case**
Now consider $p(r,3)$, let $r=3k+m$, where $0\leq m\leq 2$,

$p(3k+m)=p(3(k-1)+m,1)+p(3(k-1)+m,2)+p(3(k-1)+m,3)=1+\lfloor\frac{3(k-1)+m}{2}\rfloor + p(3(k-1)+m,3)$

Reating k times:
$$p(3k+m)=k+\sum_{i=1}^{k}(\lfloor\frac{3(i-1)+m}{2}\rfloor) +p(m,3)$$

So, for the general case for any $r$, it will involve a lot of these floor function and im not sure if there is a nice way to simplify it.

Comment: okay... not so sure how I should write my steps then.. but supposedly if I am understanding it correctly, for eg. if I am ask to find `P(50,2)`, it will be `((50-2)/2) + p(2,2) = 25` then?

Comment: Yes, but it would be difficult to figure out a general expression for $p(n,r)$ for different $r$ value

Comment: Noted, on that. Thanks for the info!